# Allow mysql connection based on seperate private IP's of a certain format

Tags: php, mysql, networking, ip, subnet

I have been working on setting up of php/nginx and mysql on seperate servers. i have multiple php servers but a single mysql server. I am connecting to mysql server from the private IP of these server.

To connect, I have used the private IP(PHP server's) which is 10.125.xxx.xxx as 
`10.125.0.0/255.255.0.0`
and it connects. I do not know much about networking but I have understood that this does a complete match for the first 2 sets of number and uses the rest as wildcards. However, I have another PHP server with a private IP starting as 10.126.xxx.xxx. So to establish connection, I could create multiple users in the Mysql database and specify this seconnd Private host.

This approach may work, but I am wondering if I could just do something like

```
10.12%.0.0/<?subnet mask?>
```

Somehow allow all private IP's start with 10.12x.xxx.xxx

Comment: I don't think it works with subnet masks, just wildcards. `username@10.126.%`

Comment: You can use wildcard for grant user privileges as username@%, and permit connections only your servers by firewall configuration

Comment: Even if you _could_ do this, it kind of defeats the whole purpose of specifying the IP if you're going to allow that many possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

User configurations are for managing users / privileges / etc **ONLY**. Do not mix this with server connectivity / blocking.

Your MySQL server should accept calls only from your (designated) php servers.

Instead of allowing / denying at MySQL level,

```
Deny ALL
Allow 10.126.*
```

at server configuration itself. And keep as many users as you want to separately manage user calls from your different php servers.

And you can not do 10.12*.